# How to implement error handling using Try Catch within Databricks sparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

Is there any way to Implement try Catch in Spark-SQL ( Not in Pyspark) like below within databricks .

I have tried to implement but got syntax issue . Any sample code would be appreciated .

```
BEGIN TRY  
    -- Generate divide-by-zero error.  
    SELECT 1/0;  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    -- Execute error retrieval routine.  
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER();  
END CATCH;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Spark SQL **does not** support a direct correlation with a `TRY-CATCH` construct that T-SQL supports for instance. As of Spark 3.5.0, there are `try_*` Spark SQL in-built functions such as ([`try_divide`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L1939), [`try_add`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L1922), [`try_subtract`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L1957), [`try_element_at`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L5880) etc). The full list of functions can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala) and [here](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-functions-builtin-alpha.html).

Similarly, you can create a Spark SQL UDF (although not performant) it will be syntactically close to the `BEGIN TRY..END TRY` structure.

For example, the following function in PySpark where there is an UDF `safeDivide` that divides the numerator and denominator only when the inputs are vaild, else it returns `null`. Then we can run a custom filter on the rows that have `null` value and handle it.

```py
session = (SparkSession
           .builder
           .appName("SafeDivide Example")
           .master("local")
           .getOrCreate())

def safeDivide(numerator, denominator):
    if denominator != 0 and numerator is not None and denominator is not None:
        return int(numerator / denominator)
    else:
        return None

safeDivide_udf = udf(safeDivide, IntegerType())
session.udf.register("safeDivide", safeDivide_udf)

data = [(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, None), (None, 1), (None, None)]
df = session.createDataFrame(data, ["numerator", "denominator"])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tempView")

session.sql("SELECT numerator, denominator, safeDivide(numerator, denominator) AS safeDivideResult FROM tempView").show()
```

Thus, Spark SQL does not have exactly an equivalent to the T-SQL construct you have suggested, you can try using simple `if..else` construct in Python/Scala based Spark to mock an equivalent flow in a simple error handling scenario.

For complex error handling you can use the `try-catch` from the Scala Spark or PySpark languages as it is much less cumbersome.

Also, in Databricks SQL, you have the flexibility to create pure SQL Scalar/Table function for which you can read through [this](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-sql-function.html#syntax) documentation.